# Creating nested elements using prependTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have written the following code that aims to create a div and within it a nested span. Here is the code. Its results buffle me:

```
function(){
    $("<div>", {
    text: "<span>SomeText</span>",
    class: "queryTitle"
}).prependTo(container);
```

When inspected in chrome this is the resulting html:

```
<div class="queryTitle"><span>1234</span></div>
```

And while this is the exact html I am aiming for, this html is not rendered properly in the browser, as the span block displays "unrendered" in the browser, like below:

```
<span>1234</span>
```

(I understand I can rewrite the code like below

```
function(){
  $("<div class = " + queryTitle + "><span>1234</span></div>").prependTo(container)
}
```

which returns the desired result, yet I find this syntax a bit unreadable, plus I would really like to understand what I am doing wrong as an educational drill.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Use `html` instead of `text`.

Comment: Could it be that the text has some angle brackets in it? It isn't html. It doesn't have tags. Its just text and renders as such.

Answer (score 10):

The `text` function will create a textNode, which will not treat its content as html (displaying the span tag in clear text). Use `html` instead:

```
function(){
    $("<div>", {
    html: "<span>SomeText</span>",
    'class': "queryTitle"
}).prependTo(container);
```

**Edit** — For clarity, your code is equivalent to:

```
$("<div>")
    .text("<span>SomeText</span>") // creates a textNode and appends it
    .addClass("queryTitle")
    .prependTo(container);
```

Where you would actually want:

```
$("<div>")
    .html("<span>SomeText</span>") // sets innerHTML
    .addClass("queryTitle")
    .prependTo(container);
```

The docs that (somewhat) describe the first syntax can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

**NOTE:** putting HTML strings in JavaScript is generally a bad idea. You shouldn't do it because it becomes difficult to maintain as the project grows.

Comment: Where is the jQuery documentation that explains that the 1st bit of code is equal to the 3rd bit of code? The syntax makes sense but I can't find where it is explained.

Comment: @LeeMeador It was actually a bit tricky to track down, but I added a link that shows the usage.

Comment: So you can use anything .attr() can set, plus any event that .on() can use plus selected other jQuery functions shown there. Depends on the jQuery version. And thank you. Not an intuitive place to put it on the jQuery() function itself until you know.

Comment: @LeeMeador I tend to use the second form as it is more recognizable and ends up using the same number of lines more often than not. The exception to this is when I need to set multiple properties of the DOM element (which is rare).